# Logging data to CSV with python

Tags: python, csv, logging

I am trying to update a log file form a python script.  I have script that generate 2 variables, inside & outside, and a log file templog.csv

The CSV file is in the format date,time,inside,outside

I need to generate the date and time and then write the whole lot with commas to the file.

I have done this already as a shell script but would like to include it all in one python script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
import csv

row = [time.ctime(), time.time(), inside, outside]    
with open('templog.csv', 'a') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Consider using some sort of implementation of python `logging` official library